# Best way to install T moulding

Tags: hardwood, transition

I am installing hardwood T moulding between my new hardwood floor and a tile floor.  I tried just nailing down a test piece but I found the slight flex in the moulding causes squeaks with the nails.  My plan is to cut thin shims, glue them in the gap while leaving expansion space, then glue the T moulding on top with a finishing nail every 10".  PL premium for the glue.  Im thinking the support for the centre post will eliminate squeaks.  Will this work?  [image][image]

Comment: Try a trim screw.

Comment: I would also be inclined to run silicone sealant (caulk) under the T piece on the tile side, so liquid on the tile floor doesnt get underneath.